# How to run a php script from windows .bat

Tags: php, linux, windows, batch-file, ftp

This is what i want to do in a batch file:

1. write a file to ftp folder
2. run php script (http://mylocation.url/script.php)
3. download a file from ftp folder

FTP i have read before, it is possible to do it in a batch file. 
But i don't found a way to execute my php script on my linux server. 
Cronjob is not possible for this solution cause the uploaded file will be changed from 
Scipt and after i need it downloaded again.

Any one has a solution?

Thanks for help
Phil

Comment: So you've got a `.bat` file on your windows computer, and you want it to force a file on your linux server to run, correct?

Comment: Yes, i want to run a php file on my linux server.
For example: http://myurl.tld/myscript.php

Answer (score 0):

[plink](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) tool can be used to execute commands in Linux server from Windows through `SSH`. Below is the syntax

```
plink.exe root@10.0.0.1 -pw password "<ur script execution command here>"
```

Say if I want to run a shell script I would type in the command `"sh myscript.sh"`. To achieve this the Linux server should have `sshd` running.

The command can be used along with other commands part of the batch file.

Comment: Thanks for your asnwer. Connect to ssh is working. But i dont want to run a shell script. I simply want to run a php file without call it in a webbrowser. To run is: http://mylocation.tld/myscript.php

Comment: Try `"php yourscript.php"`

Comment: i have try it but i cant login. Root Login is not activated for security. So i have to login with another User:

I do it with:

plink.exe user@server.de -pw pasword "php script.php"

But i get a promt: password is wrong. If i retype it to CMD i can login.

Then i has to Su right? How can i execute more than 1 command to ssh.

I have never work bevore with plink.exe

My php script must be in a special place to run it from command line? System is running with Plesk on Debain.

Comment: @Phil instead of `root@` plz provide the `username@`

Comment: Year this is working fine.
PHP Script must in users home directory.

Thanks a lot for your Help.